# sql command wrapped in form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm stuck.
I have a form on my page which starts off empty but users are able to add to it. The page I am writing is a tool used to log results of a poker tournament, so for each new player who comes along, a new row is added to a table, and each column on that table is a different input (name, place, cash, tickets won and playerID).

The place input is a `<select>` element. I need to make a call to the database to update the record when the user changes the value on the place element, but I have no idea how to do that. Onchange won't work. I can't have a form in a form. I can't use a js `alert` box.... I'm running low on ideas. How can I make this happen?

Basically, I want to do this (I'm paraphrasing here):

```
<form action='samepage.php' method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'></input>
  <select onchange='sql(id)'>
   <option value='1'>1</option>
   <option value='2'>2</option>
  </select>
 <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: would you place your code here , so we can tell you your wrong code. basically using onchange acts well! look here : https://jsfiddle.net/mojtabaa_hn/3n33bhuc/

Comment: it's more of a general question. Will update question now to elaborate.

Comment: You need to learn PHP I assume as you added that to your tags. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for that, but I'm quite comfortable writing php, and I'm aware that SO isn't a tutorial site.... This question doesn't relate to php syntax, that's just the language the answer will (most likely) be written in, and I was hoping it would draw some extra attention to the post too. The question is more about the logical side of building the page. Did you read the question?

Comment: Yup I read it alright. This bit **sticks out** _but I have no idea how to do that_ SO is also **not a free coding resource** If you have some PHP code to process the form data, then show it to us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it via [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).
basically your flow to perform described above action would be next:

Attach javascript event handler for onChange event of your select, which create [**XmlHttpRequest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to your server. On server perform update of your db and return [json response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) ( as one of possible formats) which contain new data to display to your javascript event handler and update `html` on your page with data returned by your server.

Some use full links listed below:

- [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)
- [What is Ajax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm)
- [Ajax explained in details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963610/ajax-explained-in-detail)