# ajax call returns NULL

Tags: php, json, ajax

I´m playing around with an AJAX call. I try to pass data to a sql query and receive back the data in my JS file. Somehow always the error function get called in the JavaScript

while the XHR header returns this in the preview: `Array ( [address] => Street 12 [name] => twelve [id] => 12 [surname] => twelve )`

File data_3.php

```
<?php
require 'assets/external/db.php';
$data =  file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);

$id = $data['id'];

$queryData = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT
    id
FROM
    listing
 WHERE id = ?
");
$queryData->bind_param('s', $id);
$queryData->execute();
$data = $queryData->get_result();

$data = mysqli_fetch_all($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo json_encode($data);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/json_test.js"></script>

<script>
    var ajaxData = {
        "address": "Street 12",
        "name": "twelve",
        "id": 12,
        "surname": "twelve"
    };
    loadData('assets/external/data_3.php', ajaxData);
</script>
```

File json_test.js

```
function loadData(url, ajaxData) {
console.log('JS loaded');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
}
```

How can I call the sql query correctly, so that $id get filled and the result gets back to the JS function loadData?

Comment: You need to read more about client-side and server-side, as well as asynchronicity. I suggest [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963610/ajax-explained-in-detail) as a starting point. Your `$data` is always null because that part executes (on the server) before the ajax call is even made (in the browser).

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks! I have read that and adjusted my question. I want to use now the id from my json data in a query inside php but it seems that this async problem still remains. I did figured out from the link that you provided how to do that. If it is easy fix, and would be cool if you can show it to me on my example. Thanks!

Comment: No, it can't work like this. You can't use in php something you get from an ajax call that's done on the *same page*. Extract that query to a different php file and have that file return the results. Then you can use whatever you got to display it in `data_3.php`. Note that displaying must also be done in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by split the sql part to a new file